# How to use LiveCode extensions on Mac OS X in IDE

Tags: livecode

I have an extension for LiveCode, intended for use on both Mac OS X and iOS.  The package includes a .bundle item and a .lcext item.  The .lcext can be used on iOS, by including it in the Copy Files pane; this works fine when the standalone is built and deployed to a device.  But I've not been able to use the .bundle in the LiveCode IDE on MacOS X.

I've tried putting either the folder with the package, or just the .bundle file, into either the "Plugins" or "Extensions" folder of ~/Documents/LiveCode; neither seems to work.  Does it need to be somewhere else? Do I need to do something explicit to initialise it?

Comment: On my mac, Livecode seems to create folder ~/Documents/My LiveCode/ with the word "My " before the word "Livecode", but maybe that is an old preference.

Answer (score 1):

In your documents folder, there is a folder LiveCode (my folder called My Revolution Enterprise). This folder contains an externals folder and an extensions folder. The extensions folder is where you put widgets for LiveCode 8. The externals folder is where you put externals. You need to make sure that you're indeed dealing with widgets and not with externals.

However, since you have a bundle and an lcext file, it seems you're dealing with externals, Put the bundle file into the externals folder inside the LiveCode folder and edit the file Externals.txt. Add a line to the latter file. The line should contain two items, separated by a comma. The first item is the name of the external and the second item is the filename of the external. The external should not show up in `the externalpackages of stack "Home"` after you restart LiveCode.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! I had an existing "Extensions" folder (although I haven't started with LC8/widgets), with some old externals I hadn't used for ages - I had word blindness, couldn't see that it wasn't called Externals. Now I have this loading in LC 6.6.2 - at least to the extent that it appears in `the externalpackages of stack "Home"` - but not in LC 7.1 where I really want it! 
Notably `the externalpackages` lists full paths in 6.6.2 (of externals loaded from inside the LC app bundle, and my new one); in 7.1 lists only the filenames. (Prefs in 7.1 go to same folder as 6.6.2).

Any idea for 7.1?

Comment: Have you set the user extensions path in the preferences window of LiveCode 7.1, @BenRubinstein? It should be set to your LiveCode folder in the documents folder.

Comment: Hi @Mark: Yes, 6.6.2 and 7.1 have the same prefs setting for this.  I've verified (by removing some plugins from the plugins folder) that 7.1 is reading the parent folder correctly.